How to move DataGrid scrollbar to bottom of grid?

Without specifying height I am unable to move the scrollbar to the bottom of the Grid it belongs to. Using VerticalAlignment="Stretch" does nothing. Is it not possible to either move the scrollbar or stretch the datagrid to fill its parent?

I can not believe i didn't see that. Thank you!

It seems that the DataGrid is inside a StackPanel. If that's the case, try putting inside a Grid.

If this worked, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.
